# How do I dynamically make a class/type and pass it to Map?

Tags: java, class, dictionary

I am trying to make a registry for fun, and I'm stuck on a problem.
I want to dynamically make (get) a class/type and pass it to Map.

But it won't let me, as it is not resolving the variable names into variables, but instead taking it literally as a class name.

Here is my code:

```
package com.anirudh.register;


import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Register implements IRegister {
    public static boolean isPartOfAnotherRegister;
    public static int priorityInAnotherRegister;
    public static List<Map<String, Map>> mapList;

    public Register(boolean isPartOfAnotherRegister, int priorityInAnotherRegister){
        Register.isPartOfAnotherRegister = isPartOfAnotherRegister;
        Register.priorityInAnotherRegister = priorityInAnotherRegister;
    }

    public static void addMapping(String s, int i, Object type1, Object type2){
    }

    public static void removeMapping(String s, int i, Object type1, Object type2){
    }

    public static void createNewMap(Object type1, Object type2){
        Class<?> c1 = type1.getClass();
        Class<?> c2 = type2.getClass();
        Map<c1, c2> m;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you inline the method calls? Just curious. Also, does java have a `Type` class or is `Class` its equivalent?

Comment: Java doesn't have a Type class, primitive types don't have a type, and yes, Class is the same as a type, eg. String, Integer, and Array are all of type Class. Also if I inline the method calls, IDEA throws an error.

Comment: Interesting. Ive done work in java but never needed getClass... What if you make it a generic method? Idk the java syntax, but something like `createNewMap<T, U>() { Map<T, U> m = new Map<>; }`? Of course, to access m, youd unfortunately have to declare it somewhere else, so really the class should become generic unless you only need m inside the method

Comment: @AnirudhBalaji Java absolutely has a [Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) class

Comment: Aha! @Keith would it be usable here?

Comment: @Keith Type is an *interface*, not a class. Class is an implementation of the *interface* Type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to have a variable of type `Map<c1, c2>`. But here's a workaround: Create a new method with a type parameter:

```
public static <T, U> Map<T, U> createMap(Class<T> tClass, Class<U> uClass) {
    Map<T, U> map = new HashMap<T, U>();
    // do stuff with the map here
    return map;
}
```

and then call it with the Class objects as parameters. However, note that you can't use the `Map<T, U>` type after it returns - you have to use `Map<?, ?>`

```
Map<?, ?> map = createMap(c1, c2);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works very efficiently and fits well with my model.

Comment: This looks like the java equivalent of what i wrote in my comment... At any rate, I'm wondering why you have to use the "wildcard" parameters on the returned Map? The function knows what the type parameters are, as they depend on the function parameters, and therefore the return value is determinable right? Or is this one of those erasure things?

Comment: Also, if java does `Map map = createMap<type1, type2> ()` then there'd be no need for method parameters. Not a generics expert in java

Comment: @immibis I'm a beginner in Java, so please explain to me how this code works and explain in detail.

Comment: @immibis Also how would I handle primitive types? I can't do `getClass()` on them, and AFAIK there isn't a `typeof` in Java.

Comment: @immibis Really? I declared a `Map<String, int> m;` and it didn't throw an error.

Comment: @immibis Sorry I realized I was using the _wrapper_ to the primitive types, not the **actual** types themselves. So you're right. Thank You!